# How do I override a css value?

Tags: css

I don't know too much about css so I have to ask. I have a css file that I believe resets the values. I have another css file of all of the values that I want. I can see that a td tag is being overwritten by the reset file.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: inherit;
```

How do I stop this from happening? These are the values that are being used. I have not specifically defined these attributes as I don't know what to use for the values. Is there a way to just override these reset values?

Comment: OK, what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: Nothing.  Those values are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
div#styles { color : red; }
.override { color : blue!important; }
</style>    

<div id="styles">
<div class="override">Content</div>
</div>
```

Here is the "!important" attribute of overriding CSS specificity.  Use it wisely, knowing that it will override even user-created stylesheets (which may be there for accessibility reasons.)

You can read more about [CSS specificity here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/).

Comment: Thanks JulianDroid. I'll give this a shot and see where it takes me.

Comment: I should add Tom, that the "!important" attribute is typically a diagnostic tool--typically for specificity battles amongst your definitions.  I use it for more than that, but I thought I'd just mention that... some people frown upon regular use of !important, but it sounds like your current project calls for it.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to have the override later in code than the reset. The order of CSS matters, and so does the order you have your link tags to external style sheets.

You also need to make sure that your override is equal or more specific.

```
#content p { color: red; }
```

won't be overridden by

```
p { color: blue; }
```

even if defined later.

Comment: Thanks Svish. What I'm getting is a huge gap between my inputs and I want to cut that space down. I thought that it was the td tag but apparently it isn't because it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: @Tom: If you're getting gaps between input tags, then you need to check out the margin values in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove those definitions from the reset file. But really, you do not want to to that. Why can't you just leave them in there? It's part of that reset file because those values are correct and do the right things.

Comment: I agree Alex, I'm trying to work around this and if I can figure out exactly what is causing this great gap between my input tags, I'd rather just fix it as suggested here.

Comment: @Tom Ok, I see. Can you edit your question body with the content of both of your css files?

Comment: Alex, these files are huge. I was just kind of hoping that I could get a quick fix so to speak. I have found why there is such a gap between my imput tags. I have to set the margins. As Ameer has pointed out, I could use the "standard values" but I don't know how to do this/

Answer (score 0):

You can either **remove them** from the reset file or **redefine them** using the 'standard' default value, e.g. display has the default value inline http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp and vertical-align has the default value baseline http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp So something like:

```
display: inline;
vertical-align: baseline;
```

should work, as long as you redefine them *after* you've reset them.

Comment: Yes Ameer, I want the "standard value". How do I do this?

Comment: Because I'm trying to judge what those values are so I can redefine them and I'd rather just use those default values if possible

Comment: These are the standard values.